# similar matrices and one-to-oneness of matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

I need help with this proof

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices and that there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=PBP^{-1}$. Show that if $x \mapsto Bx$ is one-to-one, then $x \mapsto Ax$ is also one-to-one.

Comment: $A^{-1}=PB^{-1}P$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$Ax=Ay$$
$$\Longrightarrow PBP^{-1}x=PBP^{-1}y$$
Premultiply both sides by $P^{-1}$,
$$\Longrightarrow BP^{-1}x=BP^{-1}y$$
By injectivity of $B$, it follows that,
$$\Longrightarrow P^{-1}x=P^{-1}y$$
Premultiply both sides by $P$,
$$\Longrightarrow x=y$$

Hence, $A$ is injective.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: This was how I completed the proof -- does this line of reasoning hold?        Suppose x --> Bx is one-to-one
1. The equation Bx = 0 has only the trivial solution
2. Bx = 0 has only the trivial solution if and only if the columns of B are linearly independent
3. If follows that B is invertible / det(B) is nonzero

Since A and B are similar matrices...
A = PBP-1
det(A) = det(P) * det(B) * det(P-1)
Since det(P) * det(P-1) = det(PP-1) = det I = 1, it follows that
det(A) = det(B)

4. det(A) is nonzero
5. A is invertible
6. x --> Ax is also one-to-one (by the Invertible Matrix Theorem)

Comment: Why does the injectivity of $B$ allow you to form $P^{-1}x=P^{-1}y$? Did you multiply by $B^{-1}$? Can you explain this step?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @Axion004, if $f$ is a 1-1 function, then $f(x)=f(y)\Longrightarrow x=y$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $Av = Aw$ for some vectors $v$ and $w$. That is 
$$(PBP^{-1})v = (PBP^{-1})w$$
or (multiplying on the left with $P^{-1}$)
$$B(P^{-1}v) = B(P^{-1}w)$$
but as we know that the function $x \mapsto Bx$ is one-to-one, then
$P^{-1}v = P^{-1}w$ and then $v=w$, as we wanted to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $v_1$ $\not=$ v$_2$. Then since P$^{-1}$ is invertible, $w_1 = P^{-1}v_1 \not=P^{-1}v_2=w_2.$ Then since B is one-to-one $b_1 = Bw_1 \not= Bw_2 = b_2.$ Again since P is invertible, $a_1 = Pb_1\not=Pb_2=a_2.$ Thus A is one-to-one.